# Designing a type MutexGuardRef<Option<Box<T>>> that derefs to `&Option<&T>`

Tags: rust

I'm trying to design a type that stores a MutexGuard for an `Option<Box<T>>` that I can deref to `Option<&T>`

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, LockResult, MutexGuard};

pub struct MutexGuardRef<'a, T> {
    mutex_guard: MutexGuard<'a, Option<Box<T>>>
}

impl<'a, T> std::ops::Deref for MutexGuardRef<'a, Option<Box<T>>> {
    type Target = Option<&'a mut T>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &match self.mutex_guard.deref() {
            Some(b) => b,
            None => None
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:24
   |
13 |             Some(b) => b,
   |                        ^ expected enum `Option`, found reference
   |
   = note:   expected enum `Option<&mut T>`
           found reference `&Box<Option<Box<T>>>`
```

Which does not make sense. When I call `self.mutex_guard.deref()`, since the internal type of `MutexGuardRef` is `Option<Box<T>>`, this should deref to `&Option<Box<T>>` and thus matching on it should give me either `&Box<T>` or `None`, but it's giving me `Box<Option<Box<T>>>`. What is happening?

Comment: You've doubled-up the `Option<Box<_>>` by defining that `MutexGuardRef` wraps its `T` internally and that you're defining `Deref` only when that `T` is also an `Option<Box<_>>`. But that fix is beside the point because you cannot return a reference to an `Option` that is built within the function. You'd only be able to deref to a `Option<Box<T>>`.

Comment: You're implementing `Deref` for `MutexGuardRef<'a, Option<Box<T>>>`, not `MutexGuardRef<'a, T>`.  `MutexGuardRef<'a, T>` contains a `MutexGuard<'a, Option<Box<T>>>`, so `MutexGuardRef<'a, Option<Box<T>>>` contains a `MutexGuard<'a, Option<Box<Option<Box<T>>>>>`.  The two occurrences of `T` aren't the same.  Typo?